# Having problems setting up SSL with Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I'm trying to setup SSL(0.9.8e) using Nginx(1.2.3) on a Windows 7 machine. I've generated a self-signed certificate that is needed, so I have a key and a certificate file. When trying to start Nginx it's failing and the error message I am getting in the log file is "shared zone "SSL" has no equal addresses". It was working before I tried to introduce SSL.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Bear in my mind the website is only accessible on the local network whether that makes a difference or not, also I'm remotely accessing the web server.

Here is the part of my config file regarding ssl:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
 worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;

 include       mime.types;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;

 sendfile        on;
 keepalive_timeout  65;

 server {
      listen       443 ssl;
      server_name  www.mydomain.com;
      ssl_certificate     /nginx-1.2.3/ssl/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /nginx-1.2.3/ssl/server.key;
      ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't use `ssl_session_cache` (and a variety of other things) on Windows. Consider using a Linux server instead, especially if this is meant to be important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The cache and other modules which require shared memory support do not work on
>   Windows Vista and later versions due to address space layout randomization being enabled in these Windows versions.

[Source](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues)

Comment: Of course you can. I'm using it for development. For production servers, I would use Linux.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment before you posted yours because I realised that the problem is with ssl_session_cache and other things regarding ssl with nginx and not just nginx in general. Thanks